# Branch link from Android always opens App then Play Store

Tags: android, branch.io

I'm currently using a Branch link on my company's website.

My Android application currently uses a custom WebView with the following user agent:

Kik/9.1.0.3591 (Android 6.0) Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36

Whenever I click on the branch link from the custom WebView, the Android OS will always open the Splash screen of my application, then link me directly to the Play Store.

If you need more details on my setup let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to open your app while inside your own app? Branch may not be the best solution for that, as this would lead the webview to fire open the play store at the end of the result.

Might be better to bypass the bnc.lt link inside your own app.